# can't access Internet from 3.2 emulator

Tags: android, http, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm developing an android app where I need to connect to some server & download data from the server
using http get

it works perfect on 2.3.3 emulator

but I test on 3.2 it works as if there's no connection ... any help ?

Comment: Can you post the exact code you are using for HttpGet?

Comment: are you able to open any website using browser?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Emulator's setting set the IP of your system

1.Click on Menu 2.Click on Settings 3.Click on Wireless & Networks 4.Go to Mobile Networks 5.Go to Access Point Names 6.Here you will Telkila Internet, click on it. 7.In the Edit access point section, input the IP and 8080 Proxy

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution
actually 3.x Android OS doesn't allow to make network operations in the main Thread
so I had to make multithreading using AsynTask